# xcode 8.3 error with generics

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, generics

```
protocol PubSubEvent {
    associatedtype EventResult
    static func eventName() -> String
    func event() -> EventResult
    func send()
}

class BGEventBus: EventBus {

    static let sharedInstance = BGEventBus()

    init() {
        super.init(queue: OperationQueue())
    }

}


class BGEventBusEvent: PubSubEvent {

    typealias EventResult = BGEventBusEvent

    class func eventName() -> String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }

    func send() {
        BGEventBus.sharedInstance.send(event: self)
    }

    func event() -> BGEventBusEvent.EventResult {
        return self
    }
}


class BGDidLoginEvent: BGEventBusEvent {
    typealias EventResult = BGDidLoginEvent

    var password: String?
    var facebookToken: String?

    init(password: String? = nil, facebookToken: String? = nil) {
        self.password = password
        self.facebookToken = facebookToken
    }

}


class EventBus {

    var queue: OperationQueue

    init(queue: OperationQueue) {
        self.queue = queue
    }

    func send(event: AnyObject) {

    }

    func handleEvent<T: PubSubEvent>(target:EventBusObservable, handleBlock: ((T.EventResult) -> Void)!) where T.EventResult == T {

    }

}

class EventBusObserver {

    var objectProtocol: NSObjectProtocol?

    func addObserver(forName name: NSNotification.Name?, object obj: Any?, queue: OperationQueue?, using block: @escaping (Notification) -> Swift.Void) {
        self.objectProtocol = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: name, object: obj, queue: queue, using: block)
    }

    deinit {
        if let obj = self.objectProtocol {
            NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(obj)
        }
        self.objectProtocol = nil
        print("deinit observer!")
    }
}

protocol EventBusObservable {
    func handleBGEvent<T: PubSubEvent>(handleBlock: ((T.EventResult) -> Void)!) where T.EventResult == T
}

extension EventBusObservable {
    func handleBGEvent<T>(handleBlock: ((T) -> Void)!) where T : PubSubEvent, T.EventResult == T {
        BGEventBus.sharedInstance.handleEvent(target: self, handleBlock:handleBlock)
    }
}

class sample: EventBusObservable {
    func test() {
        self.handleBGEvent { (event: BGDidLoginEvent) in

        }
    }
}
```

Hello guys I updated the Xcode to 8.3 and now I'm getting some errors like this:

> Cannot convert value of type '(BGDidLoginEvent) -> ()' to expected argument type '((_) -> Void)!''

can anybody help me?

here the sample file https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1zPtsTG7crPQncxYnEyWTBpSXM

Comment: ```class BGEventBus: EventBus {

    static let sharedInstance = BGEventBus()

    init() {
        super.init(queue: OperationQueue())
    }

}
```

Comment: I just updated the sample code

Comment: Hi Matt sorry about that, here a file with all code to replicate the error that I have https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1zPtsTG7crPQncxYnEyWTBpSXM, thank you.

Comment: I'll paste that into your question. I don't see why _you_ couldn't paste it.

Comment: Okay, I'd say file a bug report at bugs.swift.org and explain that this compiles in Xcode 8.2 but not Xcode 8.3.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to write the generic requirement *exactly* the same way every time. So, in EventBus:

```
class EventBus {
    // ...
    func handleEvent<T>(target:EventBusObservable, handleBlock: ((T) -> Void)!) where T : PubSubEvent, T.EventResult == T {
    }
}
```

In EventBusObservable:

```
protocol EventBusObservable {
    func handleBGEvent<T>(handleBlock: ((T) -> Void)!) where T : PubSubEvent, T.EventResult == T
}
```

In the EventBusObservable extension:

```
extension EventBusObservable {
    func handleBGEvent<T>(handleBlock: ((T) -> Void)!) where T : PubSubEvent, T.EventResult == T {
        BGEventBus.sharedInstance.handleEvent(target: self, handleBlock: handleBlock)
    }
}
```

That compiles. Finally we are left with your class `sample`. This one wasn't so easy; I found I had to declare `event` as a BGEventBusEvent:

```
class sample: EventBusObservable {
    func test() {
        self.handleBGEvent {
            (event:BGEventBusEvent) in
        }
    }
}
```